# Copying .xsd code into a wsdl

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I have a wsdl that includes a couple of import schema statements, as follows:

```
<types>
    **<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"    
schemaLocation="CDBQuickFeedbackService_schema1.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"  
schemaLocation="CDBQuickFeedbackService_schema2.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>**
```

I am using a tool (wsdl2rpg) that will create interfaces into the wsdl, but unfortunately, it does not support/recognise imports. Therefore I need to copy the code from the .xsd into the wsdl.

As a complete newbie to this, I am not sure exactly what code I should copy. Below is schema1, can somebody please advise what I should copy and where to ? I have tried a couple of times, with what I think are logical blocks etc., but they do not seem to work (i.e. the tool still does not pick up the copied code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build IBM 2.2.3-11/25/2013 12:35 PM(foreman)-) 
See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> --><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" xmlns:ns1="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg">

  <xs:import namespace="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" schemaLocation="CDBQuickFeedbackService_schema2.xsd"></xs:import>

  <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackEventsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackEventsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResultSet" type="ns1:ResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="EventSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackResultsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackResultsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="QuickFeedbackResultSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersCountRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RejectionDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersCountResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResulSet" type="ns1:ResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RejectionDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResulSet" type="ns1:ResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="DataSet" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Customer" type="tns:GetRejectedAgreementCustomerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackEventsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="EventSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventSetType"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackEventsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResultSet" type="ns1:ResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackResultsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="QuickFeedbackResultSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackResultsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResultSet" type="ns1:ResultSetType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Details" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Detail" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:extension base="tns:QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Cars" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Car" type="tns:CarType" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="StudyId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Period" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DeliveryDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="EventType" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ReturnReason" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="QuestionnaireDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Salutation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Lastname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="PostalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CarType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="VIN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackEventType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="StudyId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Period" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Customer">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Car" type="tns:CarType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Organization" type="tns:OrganizationType" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Importer" type="tns:ImporterType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ManualImport" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OrganizationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="EngineerCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ImporterType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackResultSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="QuickFeedbackResult" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultType" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackResultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="StudyId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Period" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="DeliveryDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="EventType" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ReturnReason" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="QuestionnaireDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Customer" type="tns:CustomerIdType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CustomerIdType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackEventSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Event" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventType" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<types>` element may contain zero or various `<xsd:schema>` elements, and the content of each of those can be either an import of an external xsd file (or more than one) or the schema itself.

Note that in your schema1 you are also importing schema2.xsd

```
 <xs:import namespace="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" schemaLocation="CDBQuickFeedbackService_schema2.xsd"></xs:import>
```

In your case you have two options:

#### Create two schema elements inside types element

```
<definitions>
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <!-- content of schema2.xsd -->
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <!-- content of schema1.xsd -->
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

#### Create one combined schema element inside types element

This is also a straight-forward solution since you only have to dump the content of both xsd files into an  element but you have to pay attention to the namespaces declared.

In schema1 you have these namespaces:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:ns1="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"  
targetNamespace="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"
xmlns:tns="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" >
```

ns1 was declared so you could use the types from that namespace, which refers to the targetnamespace of schema2.xsd. So if you open schema2.xsd you should see something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    xmlns:ns1="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"  
    targetNamespace="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg"
    xmlns:tns="http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" >
```

But now, since you are combining both schemas into one, you only need one targetnamespace and you already don't need ns1. So your wsdl should look like this:

```
<definitions>
  <types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" xmlns:tns="http://quickfeedback.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <!-- Here copy the content of schema2.xsd without the <xs:schema>element -->
      <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackEventsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Brand" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Type" type="xs:integer"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackEventsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResultSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventSetType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackResultsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetQuickFeedbackResultsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="QuickFeedbackResultSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultSetType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersCountRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RejectionDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersCountResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResulSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>
            <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:int"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RejectionDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomersResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResulSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DataSet">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Customer" type="tns:GetRejectedAgreementCustomerType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackEventsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="EventSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventSetType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackEventsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResultSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>


 <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackResultsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="QuickFeedbackResultSet" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultSetType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="InsertQuickFeedbackResultsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResultSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetRejectedAgreementCustomerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Phone" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Details">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Detail">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:complexContent>
                  <xs:extension base="tns:QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int"/>
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Cars">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Car" type="tns:CarType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StudyId" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Period" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeliveryDate" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventType" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReturnReason" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="QuestionnaireDate" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Salutation" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Phone" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="City" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PostalCode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CarType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Brand" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="VIN" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Model" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackEventType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StudyId" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Period" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="Customer">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tns:QuickFeedbackCustomerType">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Car" type="tns:CarType"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Organization" type="tns:OrganizationType"/>
      <xs:element name="Importer" type="tns:ImporterType"/>
      <xs:element name="ManualImport" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="OrganizationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EngineerCode" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ImporterType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackResultSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="QuickFeedbackResult" type="tns:QuickFeedbackResultType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackResultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StudyId" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Period" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SurveyNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DeliveryDate" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EventType" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReturnReason" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="QuestionnaireDate" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element name="Customer" type="tns:CustomerIdType"/>
      <xs:element name="BID" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Number" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CustomerIdType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Phone" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QuickFeedbackEventSetType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Event" type="tns:QuickFeedbackEventType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Unless schema2.xsd imports a third schema or it has something special I think this should work.

Just in case you have any issue with the copied content from schema2, note that now in this combined schema you only have one namespace prefix, and that is `xs`, you already don't have neither `xsd` nor `ns1`.

If you get all this headers right, the rest should give you no trouble since it's only a copy-pasted list of `<xs:element>` and `<xs;complexType>`.

Hope it helped.

Btw, what are those 2 asterisks in your wsdl before and after `<xsd:schema>`?

Comment: Wow, what a detailed reply, excellent, thank you. Let me go away and try this today and report back. BTW, the '**' were only me highlighting the two imports in the question, they don't exist in the real one!.

Comment: Right, so I tried to do a single schema but got an error when trying to generate my link programs from the wsdl. The error was: java.io.IOException: Type {http://common.ws.cdb.skoda.vwg}ResultSetType is referenced but not defined.  This is from schema2 and so I must have misunderstood something? schema2 is as follows:

Comment: I updated my answer. I was still referencing ResultSetType as "ns1:ResultSetType", and it has to be referenced as "tns:ResultSetType". Every type created in a schema, gets assigned to the targetNamespace of that schema, so when we define an element of a certain type, that type has to be referenced with the corresponding namespace, which now is the prefix 'tns'.

Comment: Also notice the comment inside the beggining of the schema in my answer that says:"Here copy the content of schema2.xsd without the <xs:schema> element". So in the schema, there has to be the content of schema2, for example, there should be a <xs:complexType name="ResultSetType"> so that later, you can define elements of that type, as in: <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ResultSet" type="tns:ResultSetType"/>. In sum, each and every complexType used in the schema, has to be defined in it because now we are not importing any other schema.

Comment: David, it looks like my issue with the product that I am using and it not being able to find the Client element (in schema 2) has been resolved. Thanks for all you help.